# find the manhatten sum of a dataframe given two points

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5), list('abcde'), list('ABCDE'))
df
```

[image]

and two points `p0` and `p1`

```
p0 = ('a', 'B')
p1 = ('d', 'E')
```

I want to find the sum of all elements along the path from point `p0` to `p1`.
Assumptions

- `p0` is always to the left or same column as `p1`
- `p0` is always above or same row as `p1`
- path should go down first then right from `p0` to `p1`

[image]

I'm expecting a value of `88`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you can just sum down the first column and across the row.  This will double count the bottom left item so you need to remove that one:

```
s1 = df.ix['a':'d', 'B'].sum()
s2 = df.ix['d', 'B':'E'].sum()
print s1 + s2 - df.ix['d', 'B']
```

Or, if you prefer, you can do:

```
s2 = df.ix['d', 'B':'E'][1:].sum()
print s1 + s2
```

As this will slice off the element that would have been double counted...

Perhaps a pandas guru can come up with a more efficient or more clever way to do it -- But this seems to work OK.  I've cheated a little bit and hard-coded the points, but it should be easy enough to unravel that -- Just substitute:

- `p0[0]` for `'a'`
- `p1[0]` for `'d'`
- `p0[1]` for `'B'`
- `p1[1]` for `'E'`

Comment: Possible edit: you could do s2 = df.ix['b', 'C':'E'][1:].sum() and then skip the subtraction of df.ix['d','B']

Comment: @BobHaffner -- Yes, that does seem like it should work :-)